# unable to find valid certification path to requested target wso2

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, wso2, saml

I am running wso2 saml SSO sample(travelocity.com) which is running fine with saml. But when I configured oAuth in wso2is and set `EnableSAML2Grant=true` in travelocity property file, I am getting the following error

> org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Error
>   while retrieving OAuth2 access token using SAML2 grant type   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.oauth2.SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.getAccessToken(SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1472)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.oauth2.SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.executePost(SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.oauth2.SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.getAccessToken(SAML2GrantAccessTokenRequestor.java:50)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1454)
>     ... 31 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
>     ... 37 more

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation[1] you have to set `EnableOAuth2SAML2Grant=true` to configure OAuth in travelocity property file.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SAML2+Bearer+Assertion+Profile+for+OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Travelocity

Thanks.